# Get Monday's date every week in between two dates

Tags: c#, datetime, timestamp

How to get a Monday  dates after every week in between from given start date and end date

For example

- Start date : 28-12-2018
- End date   : 29-12-2019

So the following dates should be in the list

```
Monday     : 3-12-2018
Monday     : 14-01-2019
Monday     : 28-01-2019
Monday     : 11-02-2019
```

This my code: I am unable to find the every week in between from the range.how to identify dates that its from 1 week.

Any help will be appropriated

```
 DateTime startDate = LimitVmodel.StartDate;
 DateTime endDate = LimitVmodel.EndDate;

 TimeSpan diff = endDate - startDate;

 int days = diff.Days;

 for (long i = 0; i <= days; i++)
     // for (DateTime date = TIR.NetCore.PersianDateTime.ConvertShToM(LimitVmodel.StartDate); date <= TIR.NetCore.PersianDateTime.ConvertShToM(LimitVmodel.EndDate); date = date.AddDays((Double)Week))
 {
     DateTime date;
     date = startDate.AddDays(i);
     DateYear a = new DateYear();

     switch (LimitVmodel.Day)
     {
         case "Saturday":
              if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
              {
                  allDates.Add(a);
              }
              break;

         case "Sunday":
              if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
              {
                  allDates.Add(a);
              }
              break;

         case "Monday":
              if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
              {
                  allDates.Add(a);
              }
              break;
}
```

Comment: Why your result shouldn't have Jan 9, Jan 23 and Feb 7? These dates are Monday too.

Comment: Just start from your start date and check if it’s a Monday. If not increment by one, check again until you find a Monday and break your loop – alternatively you could just calculate the first Monday from the the DayOfWeek you got but it’s not really needed as the loop will at most just check 7 dates anyway. After you found your first Monday just start a new loop with an increment of 7 days until you are after your end date to find all other Mondays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DateTime date = LimitVmodel.StartDate;

switch (LimitVmodel) {
    case "Monday":
        while (date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday) {
            date = date.AddDays(1);
        }
    break;
    case "Tuesday":
        while (date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Tuesday) {
            date = date.AddDays(1);
        }
    break;
    //Etc...
}
AllDates.add(date);
while (DateTime.compare(date, LimitVmodel.EndDate) <= 0) {
    date = date.AddDays(7);
    AllDates.add(date);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is a solution with `Extension`.
Gets a `DateTime` range and a day of week.

Returns a list of DateTime.

```
public static class DateUtils
{
    public static List<DateTime> GetWeekdayInRange(this DateTime from, DateTime to, DayOfWeek day)
    {
        const int daysInWeek = 7;
        var result = new List<DateTime>();
        var daysToAdd = ((int)day - (int)from.DayOfWeek + daysInWeek) % daysInWeek;
        
        do
        {
            from = from.AddDays(daysToAdd);
            result.Add(from);
            daysToAdd = daysInWeek;
        } while (from < to);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
namespace DatesTest
{
    class Program
    {        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var from = DateTime.Today; // 25/8/2019
            var to = DateTime.Today.AddDays(23); // 23/9/2019
            var allMondays = from.GetWeekdayInRange(to, DayOfWeek.Monday);
        }       
    }
}
```

Output:

```
    {8/26/2019 12:00:00 AM}
    {9/2/2019 12:00:00 AM}
    {9/9/2019 12:00:00 AM}
    {9/16/2019 12:00:00 AM}
    {9/23/2019 12:00:00 AM}
```

Comment: @EyIM can you please share all code? How do I call it in the main program?

Comment: Thank you so much @EyIM, can you please share how to remove that time from the date `8/26/2019 12:00:00 AM` i want output like this `8/26/2019`

Comment: @Zong - just use the  DateTime ToString member function. ToString("M/d/yyyy");

Comment: Why doesn't DateTime appear?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `for` loop to check for the day which you are getting in `LimitVmodel.Day` and collate all the dates which fall on that day. Something like this:

```
DateTime startDate = LimitVmodel.StartDate;
DateTime endDate = LimitVmodel.EndDate;

int days = (endDate - startDate).Days;

string myDay = LimitVmodel.Day;
var myDayDayOfWeek = (DayOfWeek)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek),myDay); //convert string to DayOfWeek type

var allDates = new List<DateTime>();
for(int i=0; i < days; i++)
{
    var currDate = startDate.AddDays(i);
    if(currDate.DayOfWeek == myDayDayOfWeek)
        allDates.Add(currDate);
}
```