# How to display all Fridays Date between two dates

Tags: c#, datetime, console-application

How to get a Friday date from the given start date and end date,
For Example:

- 25/03/2021 - starting date
- 14/08/2021 - endind date

I have a class

```
    public static class DateUtils
    {
       public static List<DateTime> GetWeekdayInRange(this DateTime from, DateTime to, DayOfWeek day)
       {
          const int daysInWeek = 7;
          var result = new List<DateTime>();
          var daysToAdd = ((int)day - (int)from.DayOfWeek + daysInWeek) % daysInWeek;

           do
           {
            from = from.AddDays(daysToAdd);
            result.Add(from);
            daysToAdd = daysInWeek;
           } 
           while (from < to);

        return result;
    }
}
```

That is how i call it in main method:

```
        var from = DateTime.Today; // 25/8/2019
        var to = DateTime.Today.AddDays(23); // 23/9/2019
        var allFriday = from.GetWeekdayInRange(to, DayOfWeek.Friday);

        Console.WriteLine(allFriday);



        Console.ReadKey();
```

Error i get:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.DateTime]
```

I am new and still learning, how do I call in the main method so that my output be like all dates(fridays) between the range?

[Link I followed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57644032/get-mondays-date-every-week-in-between-two-dates)

Comment: You already did call the method. Are you asking how to print out the list you have generated into `allFriday`?

Comment: yes @CaiusJard i want to print them in main method, i am calling it like Console.Wrtieline(allFridays) but i get System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.DateTime] error

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(` will write one `string` . But you giving him a array of `DateTime`. If I asked you to write a word and start giving you the whole phone book. You will also throw a cannont convert a whole phone book to a word. And if I try to force you, you will write "Phone book". In the same way `Console.WriteLine(allFridays)` will throw an error and `Console.WriteLine(allFridays.ToString())` will tell you "phonebook"

Comment: To describe your issue you used the verb "print". So you want to "print a list". In your favorite search engigne just add the language keyword "print list C#" and you will find what you want. Not that Msdn documentation on [List<>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-5.0) also contains simple loop that print the a list. And if you are looking for a particular datetime format you can also use the documentation for that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To Answer your question, instead of printing `allFridays` in one go, iterate over each element of list i.e `allFridays`, convert into string and then print

```
foreach(var friday in allFridays)
    Console.WriteLine(friday);
```

Why you are getting `System.Collections.Generic.List[System.DateTime]` ?

> `Console.WriteLine()`, for non primitive type by default calls
> `.ToString()` function which prints `type` of it(if it is not overridden).  In your case, you
> need an individual date not a type of List, so you need to iterate
> each `DateTime` from the list and print each date.

---

One Liner solution:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, allFridays));
```

---

Alternate solution:

```
public static List<DateTime> GetWeekdayInRange(this DateTime @from, DateTime to, DayOfWeek day)
   {
      //Create list of DateTime to store range of dates
      var dates = new List<DateTime>();

      //Iterate over each DateTime and store it in dates list
      for (var dt = @from; dt <= to; dt = dt.AddDays(1))
         dates.Add(dt);

      //Filter date based on DayOfWeek
      var filteredDates = dates.Where(x => x.DayOfWeek == day).ToList();
      return filteredDates;
  }

  ...

var @from = DateTime.Today; // 25/8/2019
var to = DateTime.Today.AddDays(23); // 23/9/2019
var allFriday = @from.GetWeekdayInRange(to, DayOfWeek.Friday);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, allFridays));
```

[.NET FIDDLE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3iW6qn)

Comment: @Zong, I updated my answer with description why `Console.WriteLine()` is printing type instead of all dates and also another solution in one line.

Comment: yup I read it, thanks a lot for the detailed description.

Comment: can you please tell me one more thing? how to hard-code a specific date instead of adding days to the current date? for example instead of this  `var to = DateTime.Today.AddDays(140)` I use some date like `var to = DateTime.Parse("15/08/2021")`

Comment: You can instanciate `DateTime` class, like `DateTime to  = new DateTime(2021,08,14);`, Syntax `DateTime(int year, int month, int day)`. For more details refer MSDN documentation: [DateTime Constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.-ctor?view=net-5.0)

Comment: @zong, does my comment answers your question?

Comment: however, this alternative solution gives me an error `an explicit conversion exist (are you missing cast)` and when i cast it, pop-up some more errors

Comment: I fixed it. This was because of missing `ToList()`

Comment: you are life savior @Parsad

Comment: can you please give me one more favor, how to add a count down, i mean days  left from today's date to 15/08/2021 in a query `var allFridays = dates.Where(x => (int)x.DayOfWeek == 5);` in a solution that you provided at .net fiddle?

Comment: It's easy kindly do some research or write a new question. Answering in comment section might confuse others

Answer (score 3):

Since in your Usage section, you have successfully get the result via `GetWeekdayInRange`. You can print the dates with these methods:

Method 1:

```
allFriday.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.ToShortDateString()));
```

Method 2:

```
foreach (var friday in allFriday)
{
    Console.WriteLine(friday.ToShortDateString());
}
```

Method 3:

```
for (var i = 0; i < allFriday.Count(); i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(allFriday[i].ToShortDateString());
}
```

Note: ToShortDateString() is one of the methods to display Date string. You can define your desired Date pattern with [ToString()](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1).